# How to make IntelliJ IDEA keep HTML nested tabbing?

Tags: html, intellij-idea, formatting

When i format document, instead of keeping original tabbing structure:

```
<div class="topbar">
    <div class="topbar-wrapper">
        <div class="js-topbar-dialog-corral">
            <div class="topbar-dialog siteSwitcher-dialog dno">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

IDEA breaks it:

[image]

How to turn off that behaviour?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at your settings under Code Style, Html, then under the Other tab:

[image]

You should check the `Do not indent children of:` entry. You may want to play with these things until you get the style that you want. If it still isn't working, then maybe your document isn't xhtml compliant -- that is, it may be unbalanced, which although legal html, makes it difficult for Idea to format.

Comment: Deleting everything from `Do not indent children of` made the trick

Comment: I have deep structures and I don't like random line wrapping, so I don't bother with the root (html) indenting. I can also deal with head and body being left aligned. This means that more of my code is visible in the window without scrolling.

Comment: Also you may need to increase the value of "or if tag size more than n lines" field to be more than number of lines in your file!